# Automated testing framework that can switch to an open desktop application

Tags: automated-testing, uiautomation, desktop-application

I have a desktop app I am testing that is launched through an API (using JavaScript). I am able to launch the app by making a few API calls, but I need something that can shift the context to the open desktop app so I can automate testing it.

This is my approach:

1. Call API to launch app
2. Switch to the open app to take control of it
3. Automate testing things in the app

I know WinAppDriver can launch apps, like Calculator, but I'm not sure it can "switch" to an already open app.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what were the results?

Answer (score 1):

When we generally provide security testing services we need to use such kind of tools to switch between the desktop and web application.

TestComplete is the tool which is used for the same. it is the paid one but covers almost all the features that are required in the above statement.

Answer (score 1):

Browser automation does not include the OS desktop and integrations with its applications so this is not currently possible with webdriver, selenium, cypress, protractor etc.
A different approach involving test data, APIs and non-browser testing might be worth considering but would need to be built by you.